# How to write a helper method in c# that creates a DataReader from a query string?

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-pooling, design-patterns

I want to create a helper method that accepts a sql query as a parameter and returns a DataReader.

I wrote something like that:

```
private IDataReader GetReader(String query)
{
    try
    {
        var connection = dbProvider.CreateConnection();
        var command = dbProvider.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Connection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Client code looks like this:

```
public List<FileGroupDetail> LoadGroupDetail()
{
    String query = ...;

    using (IDataReader reader = GetReader(query))
    {
        return reader.Select(...);
    }
}
```

Despite the using statements in all client calls, I have issues related to the Connection pool (timeout, transport-level errors,...)

My next step was to add an overload of GetReader that accepts a connection as a parameter. Is it a good practice or is there a better pattern?

Comment: I don't think transport and timeout errors are caused by this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the connection is not being closed; you can fix that by telling the reader to own the connection (`CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, passed to `ExecuteReader`) - but that will only address pool saturation. If the actual problem is sub-optimal / overlong queries, it can't do much. I would be very worried, however, that:

- this design doesn't allow parameterization
- this design expects people to work with readers, which... may not be optimal

Passing in the connection and keeping ownership of the connection at the caller would IMO be *cleaner and clearer*, but by the time you've done that, you might want to look at tools like "dapper", which solve a lot of problems very elegantly, for example:

```
string region = "North";
using(var conn = dbProvider.CreateConnection()) {
    return conn.Query<Custom>(
        "select * from Customers where Region=@region",
        new { region } // full parameterization, the easy way
    ).ToList(); // Query<T> returns IEnumerable<T>, ideal for LINQ-to-Objects
}
```